# Get link from checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox, hyperlink, makefile

if I have a checkbox and the value I want to make it a link

```
<a href="uppdate02.cfm?id=(checkbox value)">Uppdatera</a>
```

this is the code i am using

```
<cfoutput query="recTest">
  <table width="561" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td width="43"><form id="form1" name="form1" method="GET" action="uppdat02.cfm">
        <input type="checkbox" name="id" id="YesNo" value="#recTest.AlbID#"/>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form> </td>
      <td width="502">#recTest.Album#</td>
    </tr>
  </table></cfoutput>
```

I want the value from YesNo should be in the link
if I have a checkbox and the value I want to make it a link

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure the use case, but here's the logic to extract the id from the DOM node and emulate link behavior all the same.

```
<a id="uppdatera">Uppdatera</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('uppdatera').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        window.location = 'uppdate02.cfm?id=' + document.getElementById('YesNo').value;
    }, false); 
</script>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/fhTHs/

Comment: but then you can not click the link with id

Answer (score 0):

Hy

Try the link with this code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="return setLink(this)">Uppdatera</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setLink(tgt) {
  tgt.href='uppdate02.cfm?id='+document.getElementById('YesNo');
  return true;
}
</script>
```

Comment: If I use it I get the following error uppdate02.cfm?id=[object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: hello. Thanks but I still get the following error when I press the link "uppdate02.cfm?id=[object HTMLInputElement]"

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" onclick="return this.href='uppdate02.cfm?id='+document.getElementById('YesNo').value">Uppdatera</a>
```

have a try.

Comment: If I use it I get the following error uppdate02.cfm?id=[object HTMLInputElement]